# does an external script in rpm-maven-plugin have access to maven properties

Tags: maven, rpm-maven-plugin

In an external `postinstallScriptlet` as follows, is there a way to access maven properties such as `${project.artifactId}`? The pom.xml file has this snippet:

```
<postinstallScriptlet>
    <scriptFile>scripts/postinstall.sh</scriptFile>
    <fileEncoding>utf-8</fileEncoding>
</postinstallScriptlet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties are not directly accessible, but you can use the [maven-resources-plugin copy-resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) goal to apply filters while copying from your scripts directory into target. Your scriptFile configuration would then need to be changed to point to the copied resource under target.