# Using maven-rpm-plugin how do I to replace text in files similar to the assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, rpm-maven-plugin

I have a maven project where I create two packagings.  One is a tar.gz file (for some targets) and an RPM for linux targets that can use RPM.  I use the maven-assembly-plugin for the tar.gz file.  I use maven-rpm-plugin for the RPM packaging.

The assembly plug allows the specification of a true option that will replace any maven properties in the target files.  For example (from my pom):

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/resources/</directory>
    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    <filtered>true</filtered>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.sh</include>
    </includes>
    <fileMode>0774</fileMode>
</fileSet>
```

My .sh file has a section in it that declared the jar file for the java command line:

```
java -cp $ARGO_HOME/client/lib/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar
```

When I use the maven assembly plugin as defined above, the ${project.artifactId}-${project.version} gets translated accordingly.

However, when I use the same files for my RPM build these variables are not replaced.

Is there a way I can get the RPM configuration to work like the Assembly config?  I cannot find any docs that tell me this is possible.  BTW my RPM config looks like this:

```
         <mapping>
          <directory>/opt/argo/client/bin</directory>
          <directoryIncluded>false</directoryIncluded>
          <username>argo</username>
          <groupname>argogroup</groupname>
          <filemode>744</filemode>
          <sources>
            <source>
              <location>src/resources/client/bin</location>
              <includes>
                <include>*.sh</include>
              </includes>
            </source>
          </sources>
        </mapping>
```

What I would love is to just put true in the mapping and call it a day.  Is there any way to do this using the maven-rpm-plugin?

I am thinking of using the maven-replacer-plugin, but that is not as elegant as I'd like.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue using the postinstallScriptlet configuration, which was solved by following the orientation to use the maven-resources-plugin, that could be seen here: [does an external script in rpm-maven-plugin have access to maven properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030166/does-an-external-script-in-rpm-maven-plugin-have-access-to-maven-properties)

So your configuration should be:

for maven-resources-plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/scripts</outputDirectory>
    <resources>          
        <resource>
          <directory>src/resources/client/bin</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>              
</configuration>
```

for rpm-maven-plugin:

```
    <mapping>
      <directory>/opt/argo/client/bin</directory>
      <directoryIncluded>false</directoryIncluded>
      <username>argo</username>
      <groupname>argogroup</groupname>
      <filemode>744</filemode>
      <sources>
        <source>
          <location>${basedir}/target/classes/scripts</location>
          <includes>
            <include>*.sh</include>
          </includes>
        </source>
      </sources>
    </mapping>
```

This way the maven-resources-plugin will filter your maven properties to the copied file, that will be referred on rpm-maven-plugin

Comment: sorry it took me so long to get back to you.  I reconfigured my maven stuff along the lines you outline above.  I was hoping for something built into the RPM plugin, but I guess I was asking too much.  I use this patter for a number of other build requirements such as setting up for testing in multiple environment.  Thanks for taking the time - I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [POM Reference, Resources](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources):

> *▪ **filtering:** is `true` or `false`, denoting if filtering is to be enabled for this resource. ... resources can also use properties that are by default defined in the POM (such as ${project.version})*